# split a string first by bitwise OR '|' and then by logical OR '||' in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string `st="product1 || 78,500/- | product2,product3,product4 || 48,500/-"`

First I have performed split string by '|'

`arr=st.split('|')` then further another split by '||' like `arr[0].split('||')`

but it return result like

`product1,,78500/-,product2,product3,product3,product4,,58500`

but I want result like from first split by '|'

`product1||78500` and `product2,product3,product4||58500`

and from second split by '||' result should be like

`product1,78500` and `product1,product2,product3,product4,58500`

how we can do this?

Comment: So you want to split by `|` and replace `||` with `,`?

Comment: The issue is that `||` contains `|` - so if you split by `|` first you're also splitting the `||` into two.  Both (current) answers provide a solution, but neither explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the data using exact tokens. `|` is also considering `||`.

```js
st="product1 || 78,500/- | product2,product3,product4 || 48,500/-";
arr1=st.split(" | ")
arr2=[]
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
document.getElementById("data").innerText+=arr1[i].split(" || ")+"\n";
```

```html
<div id="data">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, an alternate approach.
Here, we replace one string by another so that split function doesn't mix up.

Below is the code

```js
//First Split
var st = "product1 || 78,500/- | product2,product3,product4 || 48,500/-"
st = st.replace(/\|\|/g, "~");
arr = st.split("|");

//Second Split
var finalArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  finalArr.push(arr[i].split("~"));
}

console.log("First Split");
console.log(arr);
console.log("Second Split");
console.log(finalArr);
```